# size parameter in asynchonous_work_group_copy function in openCL

Tags: copy, opencl

I would like to understand is there a constraint on size in the async_work_group_copy()  in OpenCL.

```
__kernel void test(__global const int *x, __local int *y) {

event_t e = asynchronous_work_group_copy(y, x, size, 0);
wait_group_events(1,&e);

}
```

The above code copies the data from global memory to local memory properly when size is 10,10000, 15000 but when I further increase the size the values are mismatched.

Also, In all the cases I have checked for only the first 10 values whether they are being copied correctly or not.

In another case,

```
event_t e = asynchronous_work_group_copy(y, x, size, 0);
event_t f = asynchronous_work_group_copy(z, v, size, 0);
event_t w[2] = {e,f};
wait_group_events(2,w);
```

In this case contents of v are getting copied to y.

I don't understand how asynchronous_group_copy function works. Can someone please explain what could be going wrong

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a pointer to shared local memory as a kernel argument, you need to specify the size of the buffer that will be allocated using [`clSetKernelArg`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) call. In this case, the size is specified in bytes:

```cpp
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, slm_size_in_bytes, NULL);
```

`async_work_group_copy` accepts the number of elements to be copied. Therefore, the maximum number of elements that can be copied equals `slm_size_in_bytes / sizeof(gentype)`, where `gentype` is a type of the element. And it is `int` in your example.

The maximum size of the local memory that is available on the device can be retrieved using [`clGetDeviceInfo(CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE)`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) call. And the maximum number of the elements that can be copied by `async_work_group_copy` for the biggest local buffer equals `clGetDeviceInfo(CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE) / sizeof(gentype)`.